# How to avoid a particular line using fscanf()?

Tags: c, file

I have a file contain assembly languages for sic machine.
eg:

```
   LDA ALPHA
   ADD BETA
   ;This is a comment line.
   ;just an example code.
   END
```

while reading using fscanf() how to avoid the comment line. note that length of the line is not fixed. Also the comment line can be appeared anywhere.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if(argc<2){
        printf("No input file.\nExecution terminated.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    FILE *infile,*outfile;
    int locctr,start=0,i,optablen=6;
    char opcode[25],label[25],operand[25];
    char optab[6][5]={"LDA","STA","LDCH","STCH","ADD","SUB"};
    infile=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    outfile=fopen("SYMTAB.txt","w");
    fscanf(infile,"%s%s%s",label,opcode,operand);
    if(strcmp(opcode,"START")==0)
    {
        start=atoi(operand);
        locctr=start;
    }
    else
        locctr=start;
    fscanf(infile,"%s%s",label,opcode);
    while(strcmp(opcode,"END")!=0)
    {
        fscanf(infile,"%s",operand);
        if(strcmp(label,"-")!=0)
            fprintf(outfile,"%s\t%d\n",label,locctr);
        for(i=0;i<optablen;i++){
            if(strcmp(opcode,optab[i])==0){
                locctr=locctr+3;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(strcmp(opcode,"WORD")==0)
            locctr=locctr+3;
        else if(strcmp(opcode,"RESW")==0)
                locctr=locctr+(3*(atoi(operand)));
            else if(strcmp(opcode,"BYTE")==0)
            {
                if(operand[0]=='X')
                    locctr=locctr+1;
                else
                    locctr=locctr+(strlen(operand)-2);
            }
            else if(strcmp(opcode,"RESB")==0)
                locctr=locctr+atoi(operand);
            fscanf(infile,"%s%s",label,opcode);
    }
    printf("Length of assembled program=%d\n",locctr-start);
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
}
```

Here is my code how can i avoid comment line?

Comment: Don't use `fscanf`. Use `fgets` and analyze whether it concerns a comment. If not, use `sscanf` to further analyze the line.

Comment: If you try to code something and show us, then we can help you.

Comment: `fgets()` need maximum number of characters. Here length of a file can't be predicted.

Comment: *`fgets()` need maximum number of characters*  So does `fscanf()`....

Comment: If you need unlimited line length, than consider dynamic allocation conversion specifier: fscanf(fp, "%m[^\n]", ...) to read lines of dynamic length. Usually, picking up large buffer size (1000 ?) is more practical, and much easier to implement

Comment: `fgets` needs a maximum number of characters __per line__. I double that the lines of your text file are very long. Just fix a reasonable maximal line length, say 1000.

Comment: (and check that the last byte in the array filled by `fgets` is actually a newline character, otherwise you haven't read a full line)

Comment: maybe it's just a semantics thing, but it sounds like you're asking how to magically find the lines that are comments _before_ reading them. That's impossible. You don't know what's in the file before you read it. If you do, there's no point in reading it. The simplest way is to read in a line, check if the first character is `;`. If it is, you have a comment, skip this line and continue to the next one. If it's not, continue on with whatever parsing/processing you want to do. To be more robust, you should ignore leading whitespace. Checking for a comment should be the first thing you do.

Comment: @user3121023 `fscanf ( infile, "%*[^\n]");` does not "read and discard all characters up to a newline" if the first character is a `'\n'` - in that case nothing is read.  Better to use `fgets()`.

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks man it worked.